# Is there an idiomatic way in TypeScript to require a function argument if a type has a particular property?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an overloaded function that should have a different signature depending on whether the type it is returning has the property `company_id`.

If the function's return type includes the property `company_id`, the function's `company_id` parameter is mandatory.

If the function's return type does not include the property `company_id`, the function's `company_id` is not only not-mandatory, passing it when calling the function should be a type error.

Below is my solution, it's working but is verbose and involves much type wrangling.

```typescript
type Data = Record<string, unknown> & { company_id?: never };
type DataWithCompany = Data & { company_id: number };

type SelectById = {
  <D extends { company_id: number }, K extends keyof D, V extends D[K]>(
    table: string,
    idKey: K,
    idVal: V,
    company_id: number
  ): Promise<D>;
  <D extends Data, K extends keyof D, V extends D[K]>(
    table: string,
    idKey: K,
    idVal: V,
    company_id?: never
  ): Promise<D>;
};

const selectById: SelectById = async (
  table: string,
  idKey: string,
  idVal: unknown,
  company_id?: number
) => {
  if (company_id) {
    return { id: 1, name: "With Company Id", company_id } as DataWithCompany;
  } else {
    return { id: 2, name: "Without Company Id" } as Data;
  }
};

type FooObjectWithCompany = {
  company_id: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

type BarObjectWithoutCompany = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

// Type error:
const thingy: Promise<FooObjectWithCompany> = selectById("footable", "id", 1);
const otherThingy: Promise<BarObjectWithoutCompany> = selectById("bartable", "id", 1, 2);

// No type error:
const thingyWorking: Promise<FooObjectWithCompany> = selectById("footable", "id", 1, 1);
const otherThingyWorking: Promise<BarObjectWithoutCompany> = selectById("bartable", "id", 1);
```

What is the idiomatic TypeScript way of solving this problem?

Comment: The `Record<string, unknown>` makes this tricky. Typescript can have a hard time with an index signature that then has exception. Is that really required, or can this be a known interface instead?

Comment: @AlexWayne I don't think so, unless you know of a type expressing any object that may or may not contain a property called `company_id`? This function is general, used in many places in the codebase and with many different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with only the most minimal of generics and function overloads.

---

First, I think you need two generic types here:

```
type DataWithCompany<Data> = Data & { company_id: number }
type DataWithoutCompany<Data> = Data & { company_id?: never }
```

Now you can take any object type, and declare it to be with or without a `company_id`.

`selectById` seems to return an object with `id` and `name`, so we can declare that type:

```
interface IdAndName {
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

---

For the functions, you are describing something that fits function overloads. The presence of an additional argument changes the return type. So you have one overload for when the argument exists, and one for when it doesn't.

```
function selectById(
  table: string,
  idKey: string,
  idVal: unknown,
  company_id: number
): DataWithCompany<IdAndName>

function selectById(
  table: string,
  idKey: string,
  idVal: unknown,
): DataWithoutCompany<IdAndName>
```

Then declare the implementation which needs to have the combined type of both overload signatures.

```
function selectById(
  table: string,
  idKey: string,
  idVal: unknown,
  company_id?: number
): DataWithCompany<IdAndName> | DataWithoutCompany<IdAndName> {
  if (company_id) {
    return { id: 1, name: "With Company Id", company_id }
  } else {
    return { id: 2, name: "Without Company Id" };
  }
};
```

Now this produces the error you expect:

```
type FooObjectWithCompany = {
  company_id: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

// error
const thingy: FooObjectWithCompany = selectById("footable", "id", 1);
```

However, this does not error:

```
type BarObjectWithoutCompany = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

// works
const otherThingy: BarObjectWithoutCompany = selectById("bartable", "id", 1, 2);
```

The reason that's fine is that `BarObjectWithoutCompany` has no entry for `company_id`, which means that typescript can safely ignore that property entirely. It won't let you access `company_id` either way, so it's value doesn't matter. You can often safely assign an object with more properties to a type with less properties, as long as all required properties are present.

You can improve this by declaring these types with the helpers we setup first:

```
type FooObjectWithCompany = DataWithCompany<IdAndName>;
type BarObjectWithoutCompany = DataWithoutCompany<IdAndName>;

// Type error:
const thingy: FooObjectWithCompany = selectById("footable", "id", 1);
const otherThingy: BarObjectWithoutCompany = selectById("bartable", "id", 1, 2);

// No type error:
const thingyWorking: FooObjectWithCompany = selectById("footable", "id", 1, 1);
const otherThingyWorking: BarObjectWithoutCompany = selectById("bartable", "id", 1);
```

Now you get the error you expect because `BarObjectWithoutCompany` must have no value for `company_id` to be valid.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2&ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=4&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOB1AlsAFgYQPYFsxwB2IAPPIgHxQC8sCcUAZFAN5QDGeBxA+igCYAuKIQCuuAEYQATlAC+AKFCQ6iVBmyjgOfEVLk4VWgaasOXPX34B+YYQgA3GfIUKUhYDIBmcdtACS-ACChPwAcnC40CwKUFACduJS0rEikRDCAM7A0u4A5gqKCl6ihOzAKNiEUJkQADYQ5QBCIIEAFKmIEg1ZOfkANKkCANIQIL25hHmDcQIAanB1wqUA1oTYAO6EM+a6vAkiSTIKAJTCBupYFsQkgSHh6RSuJWUVVTX1jcAt7Z1w3Rkan0pjsRmMJgMhvwFksoKt1ltBmdVMg0OhNNprqQ7qEIlEnsVSuVKtVag1mq1+B04l0ekDJtMoaNxvTIbNoYtloQ1pttqlOHsQFZbIdJMdkRc0TpuNjgrjHlAAD4oy4Y6V6W5yh741hDLxQNoCmVWE66uJxaQQYCiaTVNgHACM-TSUWEACJLlB1cQoIE3c6jZYBC44nIoPVambzZbrbazAcAEzOwjpd2qrRerG+-hu+QAblSijkBaU4GgADFsNgAPISABWX0u3pANBVUqxmvueIgFALymgTTg0lrDfK6cxgtbko0Wmbnfl+JLAHol1AACpl8PSaTYaSCBScQjZKAYfIsys1+uN9uT2hkr4-KlurxV2kQf1QN0CD8Ok4Fw-HtgGAyGu6BnsIg7DleY5omqWZ3p8FLtG6EhDm+H5fjmzpOlACZ-q4K5QGE2AnpuMg7nuB5VMep5TCASC7is+TCBeI7XhgzatveSFPi+QH-A0GHfth2H4QBwBQEB6AgWBdEMdITFTBBQ5sTBM4TjKXGId8lJtChaECe+zqYT+f5AA)

Comment: > "`selectById` seems to return an object with `id` and `name`, so we can declare that type:"

Sorry I didn't specify in the question (I'll update it) but those are just test types to create a simple working example. There's actually very little commonality between the types this function will return, so I don't think using that interface will work.

Comment: The point is that can be any interface you want. Maybe that's an employee, maybe it's an invoice. You feed whatever type you want through `DataWithCompany` and `DataWithoutCompany` and it'll do the right thing. However in your example `selectById` is hard coded to return that type.